# Print underscore in code snippet of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm editing code snippet configuration file in Visual Studio Code

And when I want to print this kind of format

```
2019_01_16_18_43_00
```

I tried following command in snippet file

```
"$CURRENT_YEAR_$CURRENT_MONTH_$CURRENT_DATE_$CURRENT_HOUR_$CURRENT_MINUTE_$CURRENT_SECOND"
```

But this prints bad result like

```
CURRENT_YEAR_CURRENT_MONTH_CURRENT_DATE_CURRENT_HOUR_CURRENT_MINUTE_13
```

I tried
1.. Use \ before _ like \_, but didn't work
2.. Use __ instead of _, but didn't work
3.  If I use extra space like this

```
"$CURRENT_YEAR _$CURRENT_MONTH _$CURRENT_DATE _$CURRENT_HOUR _$CURRENT_MINUTE _$CURRENT_SECOND"
```

it works, but format which contains space is not what I want to print

```
2019 _02 _15 _09 _36 _54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables must be inside braces:

```
'${CURRENT_YEAR}_${CURRENT_MONTH}_${CURRENT_DATE}_${CURRENT_HOUR}'
```